# Apache POI: Issue with Merged Regions and Styles in Adjacent Cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, quarkus

I'm facing an issue with Apache POI when working with merged regions and applying styles to adjacent cells in an Excel sheet. When I create two adjacent merged regions and apply styles to them, the content of the first merged region disappears when the second one is added. However, if I remove the second merged region, the first one displays correctly again.

Here's a snippet of the method I use to create and style merged regions:

```
private void createMergedRegion(Sheet sheet, int rowNumber, int startCol, int endCol, String cellValue, CellStyle style) {
    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(rowNumber, rowNumber, startCol, endCol));
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
    for (int i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
        if (i == startCol) {
            cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm using this method in the context of creating the Excel file:

```
public void createExcelFile(String filename, List<PackingListData> dataList) {
    try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Packing List");
        sheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);

        CellStyle borderStyle = createBorderedStyle(workbook);
        CellStyle titleStyle = createTitleStyle(workbook, borderStyle);
        CellStyle addressStyle = createAddressStyle(workbook, borderStyle);

        createMergedRegion(sheet, 0, 0, 13, "PACKING LIST INFORMATION - WH/OUT/00658", titleStyle);
        createMergedRegion(sheet, 1, 0, 6, "PICKUP ADDRESS", addressStyle);
        createMergedRegion(sheet, 1, 7, 13, "DELIVERY ADDRESS", addressStyle);

        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The issue occurs specifically with the "PICKUP ADDRESS" cell - it disappears when the "DELIVERY ADDRESS" cell is added. Removing the "DELIVERY ADDRESS" cell makes the "PICKUP ADDRESS" reappear. I suspect it might be related to how Apache POI handles styles or merged regions, especially when they are adjacent.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or knows how to resolve this? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here's a snippet of the code where the style works correctly:

```
public void createExcelFile(String filename, List<PackingListData> dataList) {
    try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Packing List");
        sheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);

        /* ---------- Création et style du titre ---------- */
        sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 13));
        Row titleRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        CellStyle titleStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        Font titleFont = workbook.createFont();
        titleFont.setBold(true);
        titleFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
        titleFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
        titleStyle.setFont(titleFont);
        titleStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        Cell titleCell = titleRow.createCell(0);
        titleCell.setCellValue("PACKING LIST INFORMATION - WH/OUT/00658");
        titleCell.setCellStyle(titleStyle);

        // Apply styles to all merged title cells
        for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
            Cell cell = titleRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellStyle(titleStyle);
        }

        // ... rest of the code ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code works fine, but when I add the following lines for creating merged regions, the merged regions work but the text style disappears:

```
/* ---------- Création et style des adresses ---------- */
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, 6));
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 7, 13));

CellStyle addressStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
Font addressFont = workbook.createFont();
addressFont.setBold(true);
addressStyle.setFont(addressFont);
addressStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

Row addressRow = sheet.createRow(1);
Cell pickupAddressCell = addressRow.createCell(0);
pickupAddressCell.setCellValue("PICKUP ADDRESS");
pickupAddressCell.setCellStyle(addressStyle);

Cell deliveryAddressCell = addressRow.createCell(7);
deliveryAddressCell.setCellValue("DELIVERY ADDRESS");
deliveryAddressCell.setCellStyle(addressStyle);

// Apply borders to all merged address cells
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    Cell cell = addressRow.createCell(i);
    cell.setCellStyle(addressStyle);
}
for (int i = 8; i <= 13; i++) {
    Cell cell = addressRow.createCell(i);
    cell.setCellStyle(addressStyle);
}

/* ---------- End of address creation ---------- */
```

Comment: If there are lines of code you can remove but still show the problem, I recommend to do so. It helps everyone reading your question everytime.

Comment: Cannot reproducing. Exactly your code works for me without any problems using current Apache POII version 5.2.5 and Excel 2019. What versions are you using?